# divs don't inherit css (they should)

Tags: html, css, inheritance

I have this simple html and css (sass) with some nesting, but not much. The problem I have is that in the first big div all sub-elements are displayed inside as they are written, but in the other div (same class) bg-color and margin cover only the heading and not the other elements in that div.
What is happening?

[codepen link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gbqRvE?editors=110)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.intro {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background: #F3F5F8;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: slategray;
}
.intro:nth-child(2) {
  background: #e8e6e3;
}
.intro section {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  width: 600px;
}
.intro section .column {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 33.33333%;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.intro section .column .item {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: cadetblue;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.intro section .column h3 {
  font: 0.6em "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  letter-spacing: 0.5em;
}
.intro section .column p {
  font: 0.8em/1.8em "Arimo", sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 25px 0;
}
.intro section h2 {
  font: 2em "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.intro section h4 {
  font: 0.6em "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  letter-spacing: 0.5em;
}
.intro section p {
  font: 0.8em/1.8em "Arimo", sans-serif;
  padding: 0 120px;
  margin: 45px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">
 <section>
  <h4>WHO WE ARE</h4>
  <h2>HEADING</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet dolorum voluptas, ullam vero est.</p>
 </section>
</div>

<div class="intro">
 <section>
  <h4>WHAT WE DO</h4>
  <h2>HEADING</h2>
  <div class="column">
   <div class="item"></div>
   <h3>ITEM1</h3>
   <p>Necessitatibus ipsa ex hic sunt maxime.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
   <div class="item"></div>
   <h3>ITEM2</h3>
   <p>Molestias ipsum ex deleniti illo qui obcaecati repellat.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
   <div class="item"></div>
   <h3>ITEM3</h3>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  </div>
 </section>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Which divs exactly are you asking about here? Not sure what "the first big div" and "the other div" are referring to

Comment: `float: left` removes the `<div class="column">` from the flow, so the color of the beige div does not extend below them. Is that what you're talking about?

Answer (score 1):

because your `.column` divs are `float:left;` you need a container with `clear:both;` after the columns:

```
<section>
    <h4>WHAT WE DO</h4>
    <h2>HEADING</h2>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <h3>ITEM1</h3>
        <p>Necessitatibus ipsa ex hic sunt maxime.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <h3>ITEM2</h3>
        <p>Molestias ipsum ex deleniti illo qui obcaecati repellat.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <h3>ITEM3</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clearer"></div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.clearer {
  clear:both;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myvwNY

Without the `clear` the container the floating divs are in has no height.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to floats of .colomn , you can use  `conatain float or clearfix` techniques

I have listed tow of them below

**1)** added `<p></p>` with `clear both sides` after floated element

**2)** add `overflow:hidden` to the parent of floated element  (ie )

[Read more about clearfix and containing floats](http://www.sitepoint.com/clearing-floats-overview-different-clearfix-methods/)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.intro {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background: #F3F5F8;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: slategray;
}
.intro:nth-child(2) {
  background: #e8e6e3;
}
.intro section {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  width: 600px;
}
.intro section .column {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 33.33333%;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.intro section .column .item {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: cadetblue;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.intro section .column h3 {
  font: 0.6em "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  letter-spacing: 0.5em;
}
.intro section .column p {
  font: 0.8em/1.8em "Arimo", sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 25px 0;
}
.intro section h2 {
  font: 2em "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.intro section h4 {
  font: 0.6em "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  letter-spacing: 0.5em;
}
.intro section p {
  font: 0.8em/1.8em "Arimo", sans-serif;
  padding: 0 120px;
  margin: 45px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">
 <section>
  <h4>WHO WE ARE</h4>
  <h2>HEADING</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet dolorum voluptas, ullam vero est.</p>
 </section>
</div>

<div class="intro">
 <section>
  <h4>WHAT WE DO</h4>
  <h2>HEADING</h2>
  <div class="column">
   <div class="item"></div>
   <h3>ITEM1</h3>
   <p>Necessitatibus ipsa ex hic sunt maxime.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
   <div class="item"></div>
   <h3>ITEM2</h3>
   <p>Molestias ipsum ex deleniti illo qui obcaecati repellat.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
   <div class="item"></div>
   <h3>ITEM3</h3>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  </div>
    <p style="clear:both"></p> 
 </section>
 
</div>
```

Comment: great link, the resource advises to create reusable .clearfix class, .clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after { content: ""; display: table; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
.clearfix { zoom: 1; /* ie 6/7 */ }

Comment: yes you can use display bloc.table use psuaedo after,before many techniques :)

Answer (score 1):

Think I understand - you have column collapse from the floated column

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEbZoP

just add a clear after them like so

```
 <div class="clear"></div>

.clear 
   clear: both;
```